# Is it not impossible to define self-interpreter in Homotopy Type Theory?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory, automated-theorem-proving

I've been exploring approaches to defining semisimplicial types in a variation of HoTT (as far as I know, it's equivalent to Book HoTT). If this construction succeeded, it would be a major step towards defining a self-interpreter in HoTT (a function from a syntactic representation of HoTT terms and types, to the actual terms and types; e.g. using HoTT as a metatheory for HoTT).

The main problem in this construction is a coherence requirement (there is a family of equalities for which we must show that a certain composite is equal to a single equality with different parameters). If one tries to write down first few such equalities, it's evident that they're all `refl`-s. Therefore, one hopes to prove inductively that they're refls. Then, however, one gets stuck at writing down the types for these coherence equalities (`refl` is not an inhabitant of `x = y`, even though `x` and `y` reduce to the same term at every level).

This problem becomes trivial if one switches to one of:

1. Extensional Type Theory
2. Intensional Type Theory with Uniqueness of Identity Proofs
3. Some more exotic type theory that somehow permits to "defer" typechecking (maybe by some notion of "inductive" well-typedness)

These systems are not HoTT, however. So it occurred to me, since HoTT is a normalizing theory, doesn't that imply it cannot interpret/typecheck itself?

Comment: The construction of semisimplicial types is a major open problem in homotopy type theory. You might want to ask on MO about the current state of the art.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you for response. Do you think I should ask this again on MO, or should ask for moderator intervention to move this question?

Comment: Since no substantial answers or comments have been posted here you can just delete your question here and post on MO. But I suggest looking at some recent papers first. There are some relevant remarks [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07442).

Comment: In answer to your specific question, Godel's incompleteness theorem implies that a consistent theory cannot model itself, and since normalization implies consistency, a normalizing theory cannot model itself.  But the way that people usually ask this question is whether a theory with more universes can model a version of the same theory with fewer universes, which gets at the main point and avoids the Godelian problem.